# GKE Persistent Volume Resize: File system resize doesn't finish

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I would like to expand my persistent volume for a deployment on my GKE cluster running v1.12.5. I changed the storage class to enable volume expansion:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
allowVolumeExpansion: true
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```

I changed the size of my PVC afterwards:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: webcontent
  namespace: k8s-test
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
spec:
  accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi  ---> Old size was 1Gi
```

I checked the status of my pvc like this AFTER I deleted the pod. The pod was then restarted by the replicas settings within the deployment within seconds:

```
kubectl get pvc -n k8s-test -o yaml
```

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{"volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class":"default"},"name":"webcontent","namespace":"k8s-test"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"2Gi"}}}}
      pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
      pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
      volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
      volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
    creationTimestamp: "2019-03-26T13:32:22Z"
    finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
    name: webcontent
    namespace: k8s-test
    resourceVersion: "12957822"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/k8s-test/persistentvolumeclaims/webcontent
    uid: 95dcdcba-4fcb-11e9-97fd-42010aa400b9
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    dataSource: null
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 2Gi
    storageClassName: standard
    volumeName: pvc-95dcdcba-4fcb-11e9-97fd-42010aa400b9
  status:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    capacity:
      storage: 1Gi
    conditions:
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: "2019-03-26T15:35:28Z"
      message: Waiting for user to (re-)start a pod to finish file system resize of
        volume on node.
      status: "True"
      type: FileSystemResizePending
    phase: Bound
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

So it seems like it only waits for the file system resize. As already mentioned I deleted the pod several times and I also set the replicas value to 0 to terminate the pod but the file system resize didn't kick in.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you checked the status **after** deleting the pod. As per the Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/), the status must first be FileSystemResizePending, then the pod can be restarted by either deleting or scaling down the deployment then up.

Comment: That's what I did of course! I waited for the status to be "FileSystemResizePending" and then deleted the pod afterwards.